# Find concatenate words in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have indexed this data

```
song:{
  title:"laser game"
}
```

but the user is searching for

```
lasergame
```

How would you go about mapping/indexing/querying for this?

Comment: you could use `shingle filter` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of tricky problem.

1)  I guess the most effective way might be to use [compound token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-compound-word-tokenfilter.html), with `word list` made up of some words you think user might concatenate.

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "concatenate_split": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "myFilter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "myFilter": {
          "type": "dictionary_decompounder",
          "word_list": [
            "laser",
            "game",
            "lean",
            "on",
            "die",
            "hard"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

After applying analyzer, *lasergame* will split into *laser* and *game* along with *lasergame*, now this will give you results that has **any** of those words.

2) Another approach could be concatenating whole title with [pattern replace char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) replacing all the spaces.

```
{
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "char_filter" : {
                "my_pattern":{
                    "type":"pattern_replace",
                    "pattern":"\\s+",
                    "replacement":""
                }
            },
            "analyzer" : {
                "custom_with_char_filter" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "char_filter" : ["my_pattern"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to use `multi fields` with this approach, with this `pattern`, `laser game` will be indexed as *lasergame* and your query will work.
Here the problem is *laser game play* will be indexed as *lasegameplay* and search for *lasergame* wont return anything so you might want to consider using `prefix query` or `wildcard query` for this.

3) This might not make sense but you could also use [synonym filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html), if you think users are often concatenating some words.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution would be using [nGrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html). That would be the base to start working with and could be tweaked to meet your needs. But here you go:

#### Mappings

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "myAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "nGram",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "sample": {
      "properties": {
        "myField": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "myAnalyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Test document

```
PUT /test/sample/1
{
  "myField": "laser game"
}
```

#### Query

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "myField": "lasergame"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Results

```
{
  "took": 47,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2161999,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2161999,
        "_source": {
          "myField": "laser game"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This analyzer will create lots of `ngrams` in your index, such as `la`, `las`, lase`...`gam`, game` and etc. Both `lasergame` and `laser game` will produce a lot of similar tokens and will find your document as you'd expect.

Comment: I thought about this, but this will give lot of unexpected results, like `late night`, `game on` which users might not want. correct me If I am wrong

Comment: @ChintanShah25 That's right. But it's only quite dynamic solution to get this done. That's why I told *That would be the base to start working with and could be tweaked to meet your needs*. Otherwise you'd have to hard-code lots of data in your analyzer, which is not very convenient.